# Explanation for `check /= 2;`

Tags: java

I need some explanation for this code. 
This is the example code given by others.

```
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 8; i++ )
    {
        if(check % 2 == 0)
            sum += i;
        else
            sum -= i;
        check /= 2;            <--- Need explanation for this line.
    }
```

But in the `Pseudo code`, there is no `check /= 2;` procedure.

Here is the full `Pseudo code`.

```
int binary = 0;
int sum;

while(binary<256)
sum = 0;
for(go through all 8 digits)
    if the i-th digit is 0
        sum += i
    if the i-th digit is 1
        sum -= i
end for

if sum == 0
    output

binary++
end while
```

So, what is the purpose for that line of code?

Since `sum`, `binary`, and `check` is initialize as `0`.

I have written this code using the Pseudocode given above.
But seems like my code will duplicate the output and one more problem, the format.

I want the output be like this format:

```
Enter a number : 3

-1 -2 +3 = 0
1 +2 -3 = 0
```

But my currently output is:

```
Enter a number : 3

-1 -2 3 = 0
1 2 -3 = 0
```

Here is my code:

```
CODE IS REMOVED!
```

Solved!

I'm too focus on the `for`-loop for the output part, hence miss the `while`-loop for the binary, because the pseudocode is for 256 possible solutions, hence, there will be same output for the front part, example:

```
1 - 2 - 3 + 4 = 0                             

1 - 2 - 3 + 4 + 5 - 6 - 7 + 8 = 0
```

Hence, the pseudocode may give an same output. So, since the solution is in `2 ^ n` where `n = 1, 2, 3, ...` form, so change the

```
 while( binary < 256 )   --->     while ( binary < Math.pow(2, input))
```

should solve it.

The format and the duplicate of the answer are solved.

Comment: who are "others"? what is the code supposed to do?

Comment: I got asked in `yahoo.answer.com`, and one of the reply give me this sample code, that the "others".
This code is to find all possible solution for a state space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way to `go through all digits`. The most right digit is retrieved by `check % 2`, and after checking it, you shift `check` one digit (bit) to the right by `check /= 2` (equals to `check = check / 2;`)

Comment: From the pseudocode, it's seems like the binary is not in `binary` form, but in `int` form. Besides, the `binary` just like a counter for looping.
And is it necessary for only 256 binary numbers?

Answer (score 1):

With this algorithm you are counting all the bit set to `1` and set to `0`.

```
check /= 2;
```

it is like

```
check = check / 2;
```

and you can use it to shift all bits right by one.
For example:

```
(binary) 101 / (decimal) 2 = (binary) 10
```

that is `101` shift right by one digit.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this line:

```
check /= 2;
```

In Java it is equivalent to the following simple statement:

```
check = check / 2;
```

Now let's find out the purpose behind it:

1. The right most digit is checked by `check % 2`
2. Then it is shifted right by one digit by `check /= 2`

Answer (score 0):

check /= 2 is equivalent to check = check / 2;

its just a way of combining multiple assignments into a single one, like sum += 2 is equivalent to sum = sum + 2;